# XSLT select like VB 'with'

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am replacing a `for-each` in some XSLT with a number of discrete calls that deal with data relative to the 'selected' node in the `for-each`.

I don't want to change the references in the `for-each`, only duplicate the code.

Currently I have

```
xsl:for-each select='FMGROUPRESULTS[GUID=$Guid]
```

then

```
<xsl:if test="./CFUND &gt; '0'">
```

blah

what I want to be able to do is create a kind of 'nest' and say `select(somehow)='FMGROUPRESULTS[GUID=$Guid][0]` and then use relative calls within.

I have tried `value-of` and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is XSLT version do you use? What exactly are you going to get - separately access to each element returned by for-each select statement? any readable example?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What do you mean by "like VB 'with'"? Can you show us the XML source? What is "blah"?

Comment: Are you aware of template matching and `xsl:apply-templates` in XSLT? It sounds as if you might be looking for that feature. If that suggestion alone does not help then you might want to show us a sample input and the corresponding output you want to create with XSLT, then we can suggest an XSLT way of achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want to be able to do is create a kind of 'nest' and say
>   `select(somehow)='FMGROUPRESULTS[GUID=$Guid][0]` and then use relative
>   calls within.

Based on the unclear and confusing question, my guess is that what you need is the concept of variables in XSLT.

Use:

```
<xsl:variable name="vSingleElem" select="'FMGROUPRESULTS[GUID=$Guid][1]"/>
```

Then you can access any child of the selected element by:

```
$vSingleElem/someChildName[someCondition]
```